# Excel VBA convert HTML line breaks (\r\n) to line breaks in Excel

Tags: html, excel

I was wondering how one would be able to use VBA and convert HTML line breaks such as \r \n into line breaks in Excel cells. For example, I have the following strings of text copied from an HTML page:

```
hello my name is pete \r\n\r\n here are a list of things I would like to do today: \r\n\r\n *wake up \r\n\r\n *eat breakfast
```

I want it to show up in the Excel like this:

```
hello my name is pete

here are a list of things I would like to do today:

- wake up
- eat breakfast
```

Comment: That's literally "\r\n", or do you mean that to represent the CR+NL characters?  Do you have "wrap text" turned on for your cells?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you might be looking for is a straight textual replacement for the strings. The following will do it for the currently active cell:

```
ActiveCell.Replace What:="\r\n", Replacement:=vbLf, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
```